How can I transform this bash script to a one-liner?
I am trying to find a way to transform a script to a bash one-liner.
I have a txt file of the name of pdf files  and I want to download them from the internet.
file1
file2
file3

The files are located on a remote server directory.
I am doing the job using a simple script file, say script.sc.
#! /bin/bash
file=$1.pdf
link=https://server-dir/doc/$1
curl -o $file $link

and the by using cat and xargs
cat list_of_filenames.txt > xargs -I % script.sc %

I am trying  - mainly to increase my understanding of the shell - to find a way of accomplishing  the same functionality without using   the script, but only through the shell and the usually installed utilities (awk? sed?)

wget -B https://server-dir/doc/ -i filenames.txt might work.

You can extend the use of the -I flag of xargs, like so:
<list_of_filenames.txt xargs -I @ curl https://server-dir/doc/@.pdf -o @.pdf

The list of filenames is piped into the xargs command. The command goes over the list and runs curl on each of them. The I flag takes care of substituting the placeholder to create the desired URL and output destination.

It would be helpful to explain what is going on here...


transform this bash script to a one-liner

Lets say your file with names is named file.txt then you can get desired result using following one-liner
while read -r line; do curl -o "$line.pdf" "https://server-dir/doc/$line"; done <file.txt

Explanation: I use while loop to read each line from file.txt I append .pdf to create output name and prepend https://server-dir/doc/ to create URL.

accomplishing the same functionality without using the script

If you are allowed to use GNU wget I suggest taking look at -i file in wget man page. It does

Read URLs from a local or external file. If - is specified as file,
URLs are read from the standard input.(...)

so you would need to convert your file names into URLs first, this could be accomplished using GNU AWK following way
awk '{print "https://server-dir/doc/"$0}' file.txt | wget -i -

be warned that this method does not allow you to adjust filenames, so you would end with files named file1 file2 file3 rather than file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf.
